# Tests are skipped while using Cucable plugin

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Im trying to using Cucable plugin for my cucumber automation framework, In order to be able to run scenarios and scenario outline in parallel and tests are getting skipped.

I tried to implement this using https://github.com/trivago/cucable-plugin#cucablerunner.
I followed each step but still I dont have success

Comment: Can you provide more information (which versions are you using, code examples, etc).

Comment: Is there any specific error message you're getting?

Comment: Note that as of version 4, Cucumber-jvm supports running in parallel